# Using delegated administration to allow custom object import

Tags: administration, security

I have setup delegated custom object administration for a user and granted them the "Modify All" permission on a couple of custom objects with the intention of them being able to use the  import data wizard to populate the object.

My problem is that after the user has logged in, they cannot view the "Import Custom Objects" link under the "Data Management" menu. Is there anything else that I need to know about how to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

Users must have the "Modify All Data" permission which allows them to view and edit all data in the org. See http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/importing_unified.htm.

There is also an [Idea to allow non-admin users to import custom objects](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bre6).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it means that non-admin users cannot import custom objects but can do that for standard objects. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.

Comment: This is still the case as I was looking for a way to create a Permission Set to do this, but the idea still waiting for enough votes for SFDC to do it.